# Python - Replacing y values within a certain x range with np.average

Tags: python

I have several regions of a plot that I want to replace.  I want to specify an x range, calculate the average of the y values within that range and repeat this process for several more x ranges.  At the minute I can only figure out how to replace the y values in each range with the average of all the y values.

```
for n, i in enumerate(x):
    for a, b in zip(xstart, xend):
        if (a <= i <= b):
           y[n] = np.average(y)
```

EDIT: The data is input in the following way:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.dat')
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

mask = np.loadtxt('mask.dat')
xstart = mask[:,0]
xend = mask[:,1]
```

ie both are 2 column text files.  The desired output is to replace each y value within xstart to xend with the average y value in that range.

Comment: can you post sample input and desired output data sets / arrays / lists?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this where the x "range" is bounded by `x0` and `x1`?

```
X = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
Y = X**2

x0 = 2
x1 = 7

Y[(x0 < X) & (X < x1)] = np.average(Y[(x0 < X) & (X < x1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slices on numpy arrays (in same way as on simple arrays).

```
#no need to loop over X
for a, b in zip(xstart, xend):
    #just replace all values in array with indexes from a to b.
    y[a:b] = np.average(y[a:b])
```